# filter based on current date using macros greaterthan and lessthan

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

```
Sheets("sheet1").Range("$A$1:$T$9047").AutoFilter _
    Field:=6, Criteria1:=">=" & Date
```

I want to filter based on the current system date where this code does not work for me let me where I made a mistake.

Comment: Replace `Date` with `cDbl(Date)`.

Comment: this is not working i have tried below also Dim MyVal As Date

MyVal = Range("R2").Value

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Q2").AutoFilter 7, "<=" & CDbl(MyVal)

Comment: What is the result of `Debug.Print "<=" & CDbl(MyVal)` that is printet in the immediate window? And how does your data look like (screenshot could help here).

Comment: when i filter the condition is not working where i have mentioned the current date 21-10-2020(mentioned as myval) it should filter greater than todays date, but i get only only 2 datas out of 10  and format of dates are 20-10-2020 08:00

Comment: Well that doesn't help if you don't show us the exact test data you used. Also what is the exact result of `Debug.Print "<=" & CDbl(MyVal)` and are all your cells formatted as date and have real numeric dates or are they text looking like dates? Please clarify, and either show a good data sample or at least a screenshot of your test data. Also see [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50349487/vba-autofilter-between-todays-date-and-todays-date-1-year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443210/filter-data-by-todays-date-and-after)

like that ?

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52340156/excel-macro-to-filter-column-to-todays-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443210/filter-data-by-todays-date-and-after)

this example

```
Sheets("Consulta_Lastro").Range("$B$4:$T$9047").AutoFilter _
Field:=4, Criteria1:=">=" & Date
```

[ex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443210/filter-data-by-todays-date-and-after)

Comment: That is not the issue. The issue is that `">=" & Date` resolves in a string like `>=2020-10-21` (depending on the date format of your operating system). But in Excel real dates are numeric and not strings, therfore the date needs to be converted into a `Double`: `Criteria1:=">=" & cDbl(Date)` to make it work with real numeric dates.

Comment: I know that...
think he have problems with that code. sry ^^.